# Finding a hierarchy of polygons

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, computational-geometry

I need an algorithm to determine a hierarchy of polygons. For example,
[image]

I have only closed loops of vertices, where polygons have CCW vertices order and holes have CW vertices order. I want to create a structure to contain such hierarchy of polygons and holes.

```
using Loop = std::vector<Point>;

class PolygonHierarchy
{
public:
    PolygonHierarchy(const std::vector<Loop>& loops);
    ~PolygonHierarchy();

private:
    class Polygon
    {
    public:
        std::vector<Point> vertices;
        std::vector<Polygon*> childPolygons;
        bool isCCWOrder;
    }

    std::vector<Polygon*> polygonHierarchies;
}
```

Can someone explain how to find child polygons and form such tree? (it's not necessary to provide code).

Comment: If the polygon outlines are guaranteed not to intersect, you can use a point-in-polygon test on any vertex to tell if a polygon is inside another.

Comment: a naive way would be to create a graph where each node is a polygon, and have directed edges that mean "polygon A contains polygon B". Then run BFS from all polygons that don't have incoming edges.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, but how can I save order of polygons? Only parent polygon should know something about child Polygon. For example, on the picture only the biggest polygon should know about 3 holes inside. And holes should know only about polygons inside them ans so on.

Comment: That's a simple tree structure, isn't it ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust, you're right, but I have no idea how to do it :8). The loops of vertices are not sorted, so I don't know how to determine if the loop is parent for the another one

Comment: Didn't I mention point-in-polygon ?

Comment: Okay, if I have a polygon with hole inside and one more polygon inside hole... How I will know that parent for polygon inside is hole, not the main polygon? (Main polygon shouldn't know about polygon inside hole, only that the hole is child)

Comment: https://github.com/aaronscherzinger/polygonnesting

Comment: @Dark_Phoenix by look at their deep. (**You** should know which is main polygon, it doesn't store the info directly is not a problem.)

Comment: @jwezorek, thanks, I'll investigate this link

Comment: If you use point-in-polygon to find and find all relationships like "A contains B", if you treat those as the edges of a graph, that graph will be a DAG, a directed acylcic graph. What you want is to turn that DAG into a tree, the tree of the longest paths to each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per what @YvesDaoust said in the comments, for each polygon/hole, you can find `all` the polygons/holes which contain it.

This will give you a directed graph. In this graph, for each node, you may have more than one incoming edges. For instance, something like this:

```
1 (a)
|\
| \
|  2 (b)
3 /
```

Here, both 1 and 2 know about 3, but ideally only 2 should. Here, 1 is a parent of 2. If you generalise this, since there wont be any intersecting polygons, if you have two conflicting nodes `a` and `b`, and if a is an ancestor of `b`, you can discard `a` (otherwise discard `b`), and you can continue in this fashion, until only one incoming edge remains for each node,